# iOS9 photos - remove image from screenshots folder that isn't a screenshot

Tags: ios, photos

So I have 3 photos in the Screenshots folder in the Photos app of iOS 9. They aren't screenshots, but they may be being classified that way since I imported them from the internet. How do I change their classification so that they're not in that folder?

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot folder is a folder automatically. The user can not handle this file. Only screenshots will appear in this folder. 
If you want to import a picture of the web (Google picture for example) in your film, you can hold down over the image and select "save image".
Good luck !